# Ошибка при аутентификации через вконтакте Laravel 5.1

Tags: vkontakte-api, laravel

Иногда не срабатывает аутентификация через ВК, когда сам пытаюсь залогинится то иногда заходит, а иногда безконечно что то крутит и логин не проходит. Использую стандартное расширение для аутентификации через соцсети.
В логах ларавел такая беда:

```
exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Class 'SocialiteProviders\VKontakte\InvalidStateException' not found'
in /var/www/mcgrp.ru/vendor/socialiteproviders/vkontakte/src/Provider.php:86 
Stack trace: #0 {main}
```

Куда копать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это ошибка в [SocialiteProviders/VKontakte](https://github.com/SocialiteProviders/VKontakte/issues/6). Для неё есть [исправление от jhaoda](https://github.com/SocialiteProviders/VKontakte/pull/7/files), которое владелец пакета пока ещё не принял.